# LDAP: error code 67 - NOT_ALLOWED_ON_RDN: failed for Modify Request

Tags: spring-ldap

I am not able to modify attributes in eclipse.Getting error
Modify operation attempts to delete RDN attribute values in use for 2.5.4.3 on entry 2.5.4.3=some person2,2.5.4.11=company1,2.5.4.6=sweden,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=jayway,0.9.2342.19200300.100.1.25=se and violates schema constraints

using this code to modify attributes:
Attribute attr = new BasicAttribute("cn", "new");
ModificationItem item = new ModificationItem(DirContext.REPLACE_ATTRIBUTE, attr);
lt.modifyAttributes(dn, new ModificationItem[] {item});

```
        lt.modifyAttributes(context);
```

Using https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/#spring-ldap-testing-unboundid to create local ldap server.
data in setup-data.ldif
dn: cn=Some Person2,ou=company1,c=Sweden,dc=jayway,dc=se
objectclass: top
objectclass: person
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
uid: some.person2
userPassword: password
cn: Some Person2
sn: Person2
description: Sweden, Company1, Some Person2
telephoneNumber: +46 555-654321

<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/ldap.properties" />

```
<ldap:context-source id="contextSource"
                     password="${sample.ldap.password}"
                     url="${sample.ldap.url}"
                     username="${sample.ldap.userDn}"
                     base="${sample.ldap.base}" />

<ldap:ldap-template id="ldapTemplate" context-source-ref="contextSource"/>
```

```
    <!--
        This is for test and demo purposes only - EmbeddedLdapServerFactoryBean launches an in-process
        LDAP server.
    -->
    <bean id="embeddedLdapServer" class="org.springframework.ldap.test.EmbeddedLdapServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="partitionName" value="example"/>
        <property name="partitionSuffix" value="${sample.ldap.base}" />
        <property name="port" value="18880" />
    </bean>
</beans>

<beans profile="no-apacheds">
    <!-- Populates the LDAP server with initial data -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.ldap.test.LdifPopulator">
        <property name="contextSource" ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="resource" value="classpath:/setup_data.ldif" />
        <property name="base" value="${sample.ldap.base}" />
        <property name="clean" value="${sample.ldap.clean}" />
        <property name="defaultBase" value="dc=jayway,dc=se" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```